# How can I return a custom class from a web service?

Tags: c#, linq, class

I have a web service that returns an object of a custom class (user):

**Web service code**

```
public class User
{
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

}

[WebMethod]
public User GetUserInfo(int userID)
{
    ITDashboardDataContext db = new ITDashboardDataContext();

    User usr = (from u in db.tl_sb_users
                where u.userID == userID
                select new User
                {
                    firstName = u.firstName,
                    lastName = u.lastName,
                    email = GetUserEmail(userID),
                    login = u.login

                }).FirstOrDefault();

    return usr;
}
```

I want to cast the result as a user object when I call the web service from another application (I've redefined the user class in this app, too):

**Calling application code**

```
public class User
{
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to bring back a user object with this:

```
RolloutWriter.RolloutWriter rw = new RolloutWriter.RolloutWriter();
rw.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypassword", "mydomain");

var vu = rw.GetUserInfo(userID);

User u = (from v in vu
         select new User {
             email = vu.email,
             firstName = vu.firstName,
             lastName = vu.lastName,
             login = vu.login
         }).FirstOrDefault();
```

this doesn't work - it tells me:

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'amstaffsite.RolloutWriter.User'.  'Select' not found.
```

How can I get back a user object?

Comment: is that wcf web service?

Comment: You're using some kind of ORM with the `RolloutWriter.RolloutWriter`. You should consult its documentation.

Comment: @Atish, Obviously not a WCF service, as `[WebMethod]` suggest its a Web Service (.asmx).

Comment: It is indeed .asmx. RolloutWriter is the custom web service I wrote (the code at the top of the post)

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a reference to a webservice, .net reads in the wsdl & creates all the types it needs to use that service.

What you're getting back is the generated type for `user`. It has exactly the same signature as the type used by the server, but it won't be the same type - that's why you get the type conversion exception. You'll need to create either a factory, or a constructor on your original type, to convert from the generated user to the original user type.

If you were using wcf, you could put the types into a common assembly, shared by both client & server. WCF can figure out that these types are equivalent & re-use them, rather then regenerating the types.

Comment: Cool - will look into this for the next time!

Answer (score 1):

Your method `GetUserInfo()` returns a single user, not a colection.  So you can't use LINQ on the result.

In your second section you don't need LINQ:

```
RolloutWriter.RolloutWriter rw = new RolloutWriter.RolloutWriter();
rw.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypassword", "mydomain");

User u = rw.GetUserInfo(userID);
```

```
//    User u = (from v in vu
//         select new User {
//             email = vu.email,
//             firstName = vu.firstName,
//             lastName = vu.lastName,
//             login = vu.login
//         }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I get the same error with the correct namespace specified. Linq is working, the issue is trying to convert the var to a User object

Comment: include the user object definition dll

Comment: When I try this I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'amstaffsite.RolloutWriter.User' to 'amstaff site.rollout.User'

Comment: That sounds like your calling application has a reference your web service application.  This should not be the case.  Could you check your references?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are trying to return a custom type from a Web Service. If you need to do this, the custom class definition needs to be included into the code calling the web service. Otherwise how will it know what a User is? If you don't want to do this the other thing you can do is return the default string objects as a string array/list/collection as the User class is just a POCO class anyways.

Please see this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15967/How-to-Return-a-User-Defined-Object-from-Webservic

Comment: Yep - I've added this in both, but I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'amstaffsite.RolloutWriter.User' to 'amstaffsite.rollout.User'

Comment: you need to compile it and include the dll it.

Comment: So, compile the original (web service) project and add the DLL to the calling application?

Comment: nope, move the user class to a library as a separate project included in your existing solution. compile it, you should have 2 dll's include the library one in the project calling the web service.